# Uncheckable dynamically created TCheckBox in Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi

I want to create a property editor because a lot of things does not supported by `TValueListEditor`. So I use a `TStringGrid` and other controls placed on it when the user enter the cells. When I place a `TCheckBox` for boolean values, the dynamically created `TCheckBox` is uncheckable. The `onClick` event handler does not fiered by the clicks (the grid fiered) and the caption of the `TCheckBox` lost its opacity. I set its parent and bring it to the front. By this time I used `TEdit` and `TComboBox` controls as well and they work fine. Somebody can help to use it in the expected way?

Here is an example to recreate the situation.

pas:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Grids,
  StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure onCheckBoxClicked( sender_ : TObject );
  public
    { Public declarations }
    fCheckBox : TCheckBox;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.onCheckBoxClicked( sender_ : TObject );
begin
  if ( TCheckBox( sender_ ).checked ) then
    TCheckBox( sender_ ).caption := 'true'
  else
    TCheckBox( sender_ ).caption := 'false';
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fCheckBox := TCheckBox.create( NIL );
  fCheckBox.Parent := stringGrid1;
  fCheckBox.caption := 'Dynamic checkbox';
  fCheckBox.left := 70;
  fCheckBox.top := 30;
  fCheckBox.onClick := onCheckBoxClicked;
  fCheckBox.BringToFront;
  stringgrid1.cells[1,1] := 'fgfgfgfgfgf';
  stringgrid1.cells[1,2] := 'fgfgfgfgfgf';
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fCheckBox.Free;
end;

end.
```

The dfm:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 358
  Top = 183
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 601
  ClientWidth = 854
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnDestroy = FormDestroy
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object StringGrid1: TStringGrid
    Left = 120
    Top = 72
    Width = 320
    Height = 120
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object CheckBox1: TCheckBox
    Left = 192
    Top = 128
    Width = 97
    Height = 17
    Caption = 'Static checkbox'
    TabOrder = 1
  end
end
```

Comment: What exactly do you need that `TValueListEditor` can't handle? `TStringGrid` is not designed to host child controls, other than its own inplace cell editor. You might have better luck simply using the grid's `OnDrawCell` event to owner-draw an *image* of a CheckBox onto your cells as needed, and then use the grid's `OnMouseDown/Up` events to "toggle" the check state of the cells.  You can use the grid's `Objects` property to keep track of the state data.

Comment: @RemyLebeau A lot of things. Collapsible composite values, active inline editors (TEdit, TComboBox, TCheckBox and custom components). I want to use a lot of component kinds inline.

Comment: You are best off finding a 3rd party property editor that handles all of that stuff, and can be used at runtime.  You are going to have a hard time accomplishing this with just the default VCL components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not work with a checkbox because the string grid intercepts processing of the `WM_COMMAND` message. When you click the checkbox, a `WM_COMMAND` notification is sent to its parent - which is the string grid. The grid, in `TCustomGrid.WMCommand` of 'Vcl.Grids', checks if the notification is from its inplace editor and discards the message otherwise.

You can modify the processing of the message on the grid to change the behavior. One way is to derive a new control. E.g.

```
type
  TStringGrid = class(vcl.grids.TStringGrid)
  protected
    procedure WMCommand(var Message: TWMCommand); message WM_COMMAND;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    ....

...

procedure TStringGrid.WMCommand(var Message: TWMCommand);
var
  Control: TWinControl;
begin
  inherited;
  Control := FindControl(Message.Ctl);
  if Assigned(Control) and (Control <> InplaceEditor) then
    Control.Perform(Message.Msg, MakeWParam(Message.ItemID, Message.NotifyCode),
        Message.Ctl);
end;
```

Then the `OnClick` will fire. You don't need `BringToFront`, it works among sibling controls.

---

Regarding opacity, it's the checkbox's default appearance. You can verify this by placing a checkbox overlapping a label on the form itself.

Comment: FWIW placing the checkbox on a panel would be simpler and help both with the click and opacity.

Comment: The event handling problem solved. Thanks a lot. But the transparent caption is not the default behavior of TCheckBox. I placed the static one in the example to convince it. The caption of static control covers its background first and then writes the text. There should be a property to influence the drawing of the control. (I did not find any in the documentation)

Comment: Your TPanel recommendition solved my other problem as well. This is a good idea. Thanks a lot again! :)

Comment: @sertac, I just use a pair of 12x12 PNG images rendered in the OnDrawCell event, but I'm just curious - how does your suggestion of placing the checkbox on a panel work?